# Vectorizing a working custom similarity function further using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am new to python, and even more new to vectorization. I have attempted to vectorize a custom similarity function that should return a matrix of pairwise similarities between each row in an input array.

**IMPORTS:**

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
```

**INPUT**:

```
np.random.seed(11)

a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 10])
b = np.array([0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 5])
c = np.array([0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 1, 10, 0, 0, 5])

m = np.array((a,b,c))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
custom_func(m)

array([[   0,  440, 1903],
       [ 440,    0, 1603],
       [1903, 1603,    0]])
```

**FUNCTION:**

```
def custom_func(arr):
    diffs = 0
    max_k = 6
    
    for n in range(1, max_k):

        arr1 = np.array([np.sum(i, axis = 1) for i in sliding_window_view(arr, window_shape = n, axis = 1)])
    
        # this function uses np.maximum and np.minimum to subtract the max and min elements (element-wise) between two rows and then sum up the entire of that subtraction
        diffs += np.sum((np.array([np.maximum(arr1[i[0]], arr1[i[1]]) for i in product(np.arange(len(arr1)), np.arange(len(arr1)))]) - np.array([np.minimum(arr1[i[0]], arr1[i[1]]) for i in product(np.arange(len(arr1)), np.arange(len(arr1)))])), axis = 1) * n
    
    diffs = diffs.reshape(len(arr), -1)
    
    return diffs
```

The function is quite simple, it sums up the element-wise differences between max and minimum of rows in N sliding windows. This function is much faster than what I was using before finding out about vectorization today (for loops and pandas dataframes yay).

My first thought is to figure out a way to find both the minimum and maximum of my arrays in a single pass since I currently THINK it has to do two passes, but I was unable to figure out how. Also there is a for loop in my current function because I need to do this for multiple N sliding windows, and I am not sure how to do this without the loop.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT 1: There was a suggestion of removing the first list comprehension in my function with `arr1 = sliding_window_view(arr, window_shape = n, axis = 1).sum(axis=2)` but that actually slowed the function down significantly on larger datasets for some reason.